# access query to get records from multiple table

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to get records from 5 tables , and finally i have done it but now i want unique records , so what should i change in my query?

```
SELECT
  t.*,
  sh.invoice_Number AS sale_inv_no,
  sh.invoice_date AS sale_inv_date,
  sh.from_Date AS sale_from,
  sh.to_Date AS sale_to,
  sh.number_Of_Months AS sale_nom,
  c.cName AS cust_name,
  h.hName AS ho_name,
  [hSize1] & 'X' & [hSize2] & '=' & [hSize_SQF] AS ho_size,
  h.hLocation AS ho_loc,
  c.cMobile AS cust_mob,
  f.firmName AS firm_name
FROM
  (
    (
      (
          adv_tbl_transactions AS t
       RIGHT JOIN
          adv_tbl_Sale_Hoardings AS sh
       ON t.tra_code = sh.transaction_code
      ) LEFT JOIN adv_tbl_Hoardings AS h
        ON sh.hid = h.ID
    ) LEFT JOIN tbl_Firms AS f
      ON sh.e_fid = f.ID
  ) LEFT JOIN tbl_Customers AS c
    ON sh.cid = c.ID
WHERE
  (((t.e_fid)=1));
```

it gives me output like below

```
srNo | Hoarding    | customers   |  transaction details  | advance  | balance | total
1    | Name: h1    | Cust1       |  inv no : 1           | 6000     | 1000    | 70000
2    | Name: h1    | Cust1       |  inv no : 1           | 6000     | 1000    | 70000
3    | Name: h2    | Cust2       |  inv no : 2           | 3000     | 1000    | 40000
4    | Name: h2    | Cust2       |  inv no : 2           | 3000     | 1000    | 40000
```

I want to output like below

```
srNo | Hoarding    | customers   |  transaction details  | advance  | balance | total
1    | Name: h1    | Cust1       |  inv no : 1           | 6000     | 1000    | 70000
2    | Name: h2    | Cust2       |  inv no : 2           | 3000     | 1000    | 40000
```

i want distict column entry_no

Comment: 'it gives me output like below' - you sure about that? The columns are completely different! Presumably there are a load more columns to the right in the actual output...?

Comment: yes, there are more columns but i am not able to attach image here so i can show you my report's data, i just give some columns here

Comment: The contents of the other columns is crucial to determining why Nasir's solution isn't working for you.

Comment: @Chris Rolliston : that only i am trying to find out

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct` keyword:

```
select distinct t.*,
       sh.invoice_Number AS sale_inv_no,
       sh.invoice_date AS sale_inv_date,
       sh.from_Date AS sale_from,
       sh.to_Date AS sale_to,
       sh.number_Of_Months AS sale_nom,
       c.cName AS cust_name,
       h.hName AS ho_name,
       [hSize1] & 'X' & [hSize2] & '=' & [hSize_SQF] AS ho_size,
       h.hLocation AS ho_loc,
       c.cMobile AS cust_mob,
       f.firmName AS firm_name
FROM (((adv_tbl_transactions AS t 
        RIGHT JOIN adv_tbl_Sale_Hoardings AS sh 
        ON t.tra_code = sh.transaction_code)
        LEFT JOIN adv_tbl_Hoardings AS h
        ON sh.hid = h.ID)
        LEFT JOIN tbl_Firms AS f ON sh.e_fid = f.ID)
        LEFT JOIN tbl_Customers AS c
        ON sh.cid = c.ID
WHERE (((t.e_fid)=1)) ;
```

Comment: I try like "select DISTINCT sh.entry_no" before all columns, but it still showing duplicate records

Comment: @Raj - what happens if you only select the columns actually shown in the example output? My guess is that data in columns you haven't shown is different, because Nasir's answer is correct given the information you have given.

Comment: with above query access giving duplicate records, actually duplicate records are existed there but i want distinct entry_no or invoice_no records.
i used above query but not working